# Is there any python xmpp library that supports adding/removing users?

Tags: python, xmpp, ejabberd

Right now I have a python class that creates user/deletes users by executing "ejabberdctl register/unregister" commands. Is there a python xmpp library that supports adding/removing users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have an implementation of [XEP-0077](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html): In-Band Registration.  [xmpppy](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/) does appear to support this:

```
import sys
import os
import xmpp

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print "Syntax: register.py [JID] [Password]"
    sys.exita(64)

jid=xmpp.protocol.JID(sys.argv[1])
cli=xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(), debug=[])
cli.connect()

# getRegInfo has a bug that puts the username as a direct child of the
# IQ, instead of inside the query element.  The below will work, but
# won't return an error when the user is known, however the register
# call will return the error.
xmpp.features.getRegInfo(cli,
                         jid.getDomain(),
                         #{'username':jid.getNode()},
                         sync=True)

if xmpp.features.register(cli,
                          jid.getDomain(),
                          {'username':jid.getNode(),
                           'password':sys.argv[2]}):
    sys.stderr.write("Success!\n")
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    sys.stderr.write("Error!\n")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. BTW do you recommend xmppy over sleekxmpp?

Comment: In general, I prefer Sleek, but xmpppy had iq:register support in it.  Adding iq:register support to Sleek would be easy, though.

Comment: I tried adding iq:register on sleek using the plugin from their wiki but couldn't get it to run. Have you done this already? Any sample code I could look at?

Answer (score 1):

xmpppy looks to have all the various methods for manipulating a client's roster.

Never used this myself, but the API documentation for the Roster class lists: delItem(self, jid) and setItem(self, jid) that remove and add the specified jid to the roster.

http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/

http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/

Comment: If its a roster then if I'm correct it assumes there's already a user. What I really want is to add another user and not add a user to another user's roster. I have installed an ejabber server on my local and I want to add the user foobar so it'll have the jid foobar@localhost.